# Prevent page to reload or move up after jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `toggle` and `slideDown` functions to show/hide `buttons` and `Divs`. Everything works fine - besides the fact - that whenever I click on a button, the page reloads and the effect of `slideDown` is too close to the bottom that the user can't see it. How can I prevent that?

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#banner_step_2").hide();
$("#next_btn_info_id").click(function(){
    $("#banner_step_2").slideDown(500);
  });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="next_btn_info" id="next_btn_info_id">
   <a href="#"><?php echo $lang ['next']; ?></a>
</div>  

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<article class="order_form_banner_step_2" id="banner_step_2">
</article>
```

Sorry for the wrong information, I just noticed that the page is not reloading but simply just sliding up when the `slideDown` function is active. So my problem is still that everything happens at the bottom and outside of the screen. How can I have a `slideDown` function but at the same time `scrolling` together with it down to the top of that `Div`?

Comment: reload and slidedown can't occur the way you describe. If page gets reloaded, script starts all over again

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault();` or `return false;` inside your function is what you need as a solution.

Comment: Of course he should also pass the `e` as an argument in the functions.